# Java 8 expression fill list from list with another list inside

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to reach a lambda expression avoiding doing this:

```
for (OrderEntity o: onEntryL) {
    for(GeoFenceEventEntity g: o.getGeoFenceEvent()){
        if(null != g.getEndAt() && g.getDynamoGeofenceType().equalsIgnoreCase("WAREHOUSE")){
            //all of them, get data
        }
    }
}
```

And on Lambda trying something like this (with errors):

```
List<OrderEntity> chargingL = onEntryL.stream()
                              .map(o->o.getGeoFenceEvent().stream()
                              .map(g->null != g.getEndAt() && g.getDynamoGeofenceType().equalsIgnoreCase("WAREHOUSE"))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Appreciate any help, regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, update for comment. Assuming you take the `OrderEntry` if any `GeoFenceEventEntity` meets your conditions then you can use

```
List<OrderEntity> chargingL = onEntryL
           .stream()
           .filter(o -> o.getGeoFenceEvent().stream().anyMatch(g -> null != g.getEndAt() && g.getDynamoGeofenceType().equalsIgnoreCase("WAREHOUSE")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, actually it is a List<OrderEntity> not a List<GeoFenceEventEntity> and gives me an error on your example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `flatMap` with `filter`.

```java
onEntryL.stream()
        .map(OrderEntity::getGeoFenceEvent)
        .flatMap(e -> e.stream().filter(g -> null != g.getEndAt() && g.getDynamoGeofenceType().equalsIgnoreCase("WAREHOUSE")))
        .flatMap(g -> g.getData().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay Adam, is the second flatMap necessary? I don't need to stream anything in that moment but if I remove that flatMap gives me an error: **Incopatible types. Required List<OrderEntity>**

Comment: Can you edit your questions to show what the output is in the for loop case?